# Обращение к объекту по указателю выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, указатели, объекты

Есть код на С++:

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class test{
    public:
      int sd;
      string po;
      const char* ol;
      float asd;
    };

    int main(){
      test *s;
      s->sd=49;
      s->po="SAP";
      s->ol="ASdP";
      s->asd=20.1;
      cout<<s->sd<<s->po<<s->ol<<s->asd;
    }
```

Компиляция проходит успешно,только при выполнении программа закрывается выдавая ошибку.Если использовать простой объект(не указательный) программа работает хорошо.Объясните пожалуйста в чем же проблема?

Comment: Нужно выделить память под указатель

Comment: test *s = new test;

Comment: Проблема в том, что указатель не указывает ни на какой объект.

Comment: Ответьте на один вопрос - **куда** указывает `s`? Куда вы все это пишете?

Comment: @VTT когда пишем const char *name; мы же тоже не указываем..

Comment: Правильно, и пока не присвоим этому указателю значение указателя на какой-то конкретный объект, то он будет продолжать не указывать ни на какой объект.

Comment: @VTT,  красиво сказали, вспомнилось: " это элементарно, Ватсон..."

Comment: Лучше пусть  test  s  будет обьектом,  тогда  s.sd=49; ... или  s = &test();

Comment: @Nick под указатель память выделена уже

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: `s = &test();` O_o !

Comment: @AnT,  наверное нетрудно понять, что я имел ввиду адрес какого то обьекта